# Forms checkbox validation message

Tags: sitecore-forms

I am creating a registration form in Sitecore 9 Forms with some basic fields and a terms and conditions checkbox field which contains 3 lines of label. I have set the checkbox field as mandatory field. If I click on the submit button, the validation message for the checkbox is showing the full label text as a validation message.

Is it possible to change the required validation message for a checkbox?

Answer (score 0):

You can find the validators in the Sitecore Content Editor at `/sitecore/system/Settings/Forms/Validations`.

Each validator has a `Message` field. Create versions of the validator item in all the languages needed and fill (or update) the message field as desired. Just check that the message is valid: the parameters (like "`{0}`") in the text need to match the original value. A developer will recognize this syntax - all translations do need this token as it will be replaced by the field name when displaying the error.

You might notice that the most used validation - required field - is not in the list. That is because this is a special case.. also on a Forms field, you would not select a required validator, but just tick the required checkbox.

The code for the **required field** validation works in a different way and the message will come from the Sitecore dictionary. If you want to update or translate it, you need to add a key to that Dictionary. This can be done in the master database - just add an item in the `/system/Dictionary` - the name doesn't really matter. The key however needs to be exactly "`{0} is required.`". The phrase can be anything you want, just remember to add the `{0}` token.

As you noticed, the ootb solution will always use the title of your field in the message. If you don't want that, you'll need to find a solution on your form itself. You could try to make the label itself smaller and display the rest as plain text.

https://ggullentops.blogspot.com/2017/10/sitecore-9-forms-translating-error.html

If you also need a solution for the client-side, you need jquery localization: https://ggullentops.blogspot.com/2019/04/sitecore-9-forms-translating-client-error.html